# Why is the Null column on mySQL table set to yes in Spring Application

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm passing latitude, longitude, and address values from an ajax query on a JSP page to a controller in my spring application, so I can save them to my MySQL database. I know the values have been sent successfully from the ajax query on the client side as I've included a print statement to show the sent values in the console (for which the correct data prints). However, when I went to check the DB to see if the values were added, only the latitude and longitude values were added and the address (area_name in the table) is null.

```
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
| area_id | area_name | latitude   | longitude          |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|       1 | NULL      | 53.3348279 | -6.269547099999954 |
|       2 | NULL      | 53.3498053 | -6.260309699999993 |
|       3 | NULL      |   53.39907 | -6.281790799999953 |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

I then had a look to see how the table was set up and it seems the null column is set to yes for area_name which might explain why only this column returns a null.

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| area_id   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| area_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| latitude  | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| longitude | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

To me, this sounds like an SQL issue and not a spring issue so I've excluded the area model class, and the method in the controller class to keep the question concise but if this is wrong I have the relevant code ready to be added to the question.

Comment: Either you are updating with the wrong query or you aren't mapping the incoming results to the actual entity being stored. Looks like a mapping issue to me and the field actually going into the database is `null` instead of containing the value from the web.

Comment: Sounds to me you forget to set the area_name in the insert query.. Can't say that for sure because you didn't include the source code.

Comment: I don't use any queries as it can be done through the entity, repository and controller. The problem was, I had the variable called address in the front end and had it called areaName in the entity so nothing was getting passed through. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had the variable called address in the front end and had it called areaName in the entity so nothing was getting passed through.